# Benefit of JSX In react native?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I am working on a react native project but I am a little bit confused to use JSX. Am I want to know what is the total benefit of the use of JSX in react native?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html (not you're *not* required to use it).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: @PrathameshMore Added thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use JSX, but JSX makes it easier to write react applications due to that JSX convert HTML tags into react elements and it allows you to write HTML directly within your JavaScript.

Comment: Hey,
I have updated a question can you please provide the answer for this, Thank you for your time.